# How to keep image from rotating when exported to .pdf

Tags: graphics

Image displays as it should when previewed in Overleaf, but when I download the pdf, the image rotates within the frame. How do I keep the image itself from rotating?

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=13.5cm,height=17.5cm]{L6P1.jpg}
\caption{Figure 1: Page 1}
\end{figure}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This could be a rotation metadata flag in the image file, which is respected in one view but not in the PDF export. You could try a tool like manytools.org/image/rotate-image (or XnView or many others) to remove the metadata rotation from the image.

Comment: This worked! Many thanks :)

Comment: @PNWonderlander how did you figure out the rotation issue? Could you add your solution down below for others?

Comment: Hey Rylan, I used the  manytools.org/image/rotate-image link and rotated the image, saved it, and imported the altered image into Overleaf. Best, Madi

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know the right answer but i just rotated 270 degrees and you will have to invert the width and height, so the code is going to be like:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=17.5cm,height=13.5cm, angle = 270]{L6P1.jpg}
\caption{Figure 1: Page 1}
\end{figure}
```